# Insert increasing console.log counter through multiple lines in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode I often add multiple `console.log(n)` in different parts of a function, for debugging.

Is there a way to do this?:

1. Ctrl click to create multiple cursors
2. Run a command to add console.log with increasing numbers, starting from 1.

For example:

```js
console.log(1)

console.log(2)
```

Placed where the cursors are at?

Comment: What are you doing with them?

Comment: Usually checking what branches in if-else something ran into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that if you're using VS Code's builtin debugger, I'm pretty sure the debug console will show you what file and line a console.log originates from, so I don't see what benefit this adds in that case. Also note that [log points](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/07/12/introducing-logpoints-and-auto-attach#_introducing-logpoints) are a thing (breakpoints that don't break and just log. Right click in the breakpoint gutter and select "Add Log Point..."). For running in the integrated terminal, or outside of VS Code, sure, this might be useful.

You could use [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). The secret ingredient is [snippet variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables). You have a lot of options depending on what you want: `TM_LINE_INDEX`, `TM_LINE_NUMBER`, `CURSOR_INDEX`, `CURSOR_NUMBER`. You could even use `TM_CURRENT_LINE` (the contents of the line. You could place your cursors at the end or beginning of the lines you want to put "log points" at, and then use newlines in your snippet body, though you'd need to manually escape some quote characters).

Ex. in a snippet file, define one such as this:

```json
"numbered console.log": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": ["console.log(\"$CURSOR_INDEX\")"]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to remove these lines after the debugging.

Another way is to use **Log Break Points**.

You can add one with: **Run** > **New Breakpoint** > **Logpoint...**